# Bounds on the maximum eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix of a graph.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I managed to prove the following result for the maximum eigenvalue:

$$
d_\text{avg}\leq \lambda_{\max} \leq \Delta(G)
$$

where $d_\text{avg}$ is the average degree of the graph while $\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree.

Now I need  to prove that:

$$
\frac 1 m \sum_{i\sim j} \sqrt{d_id_j} \leq \lambda_{\max} \leq \max_i \frac 1 {d_i} \sum_{i\sim j} \sqrt{d_id_j}.
$$

Here $m$ is the number of edges and $d_i$ is the degree of node $i$. The sum runs for all the adjcent vertices of the graph.
I was thinking about using some bounds on the Laplacian's eigenvalues but still I don't find a solution. Can someone help me?

Comment: I think I solved the problem just selecting accurately the vector in the Rayleigh ratio and using the Courant-Fisher theorem for the upper bound. I don't have a lot of time to wrote it here but if someone needs the proof we can discuss about it.